# how classification scores are interpreted?

Tags: classification, optimization, probability, score

I would like to know how to interpret  classification scores (i am not sure about the word score or probability, please correct me). For example, for a binary classification positive values are labeled as 1, and -1 for negative ones. Now, is it fair to say that for a score 10 the instance is more likely to be successfully predicted than a score 5, despite the result that can be wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scores have values that are higher than 1, I wouldn't call them probabilities. Probabilities should always be between 0 and 1.

And indeed, the higher the score, the more likely an example is to be positive, this is the most natural interpretation of a score.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your confusion but not the individual "how to" i.e. How a Decision Tree calculates probability etc. You may search the internet *e.g. "How Decision Tree works etc."*

**Score** is mostly used to describe the over-all prediction result of the model. There are many different techniques i.e. metrics for this *e.g. Accuracy, RMS, ROCAUC* depending upon the prediction type and some other specific conditions.

**Probability** tells us how confident the model is about its prediction.

Different models have different techniques to calculate the probability but in a very simple language, *its proportional to the distance of the data points from the decision boundary the model has learnt from the training data.*

As in the image, upper red-circled will have more probability of being "Yellow"

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

> is it fair to say that for a score 10 the instance is more likely to be successfully predicted than a score 5

**Yes**, *you can see that, the lower red circled point has more chance of being miss classified due to model bias.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by reading your response, i doubt if  my score term definition is the correct one. My question is not about using metrics to evaluate the prediction results. Let's say, for instance, an SVM classifier ( or other models) with a score function that ouputs values not in the range of [0, 1], where positive ones are labeld as 1 and negative as -1. These values are not used to assess the model performance, they just tell us on which class belongs the prediction for a specefic instance. For sure, we can't call them probabilities but does the term score is correct in my case.

Comment: There are 3 steps(in general) - 1. First,  the actual technical characteristics e.g. distance from support vector in case of SVM.    2. Then, using that get a probability(ignoring impl. detail, in some cases sigmoid, softmax are used). 3. Then a Threshold is used which is a hyper-parameter(you try multiple and check the best) e.g 0.4 > =1 <0.4 =0. Default is 0.5 ...So to summarize these 0,1 are derived from probability, we should rely more on probability. Just to avoid confusion - Some algo get the 0,1 naturally e.g. SVM and derivation is done for the probability

Comment: "...but does the term score is correct in my case....", These should be called as Class e.g. 0-Fail, 1-Pass, Dog/Cat, Cancer/healthy etc.